# php: preg replace a single question mark?

Tags: php, regex

How do I replace a single question mark with preg replace.

Comment: It might be worth adding a few test strings with what you want the after replacement value to be so we can understand what a single question mark means to you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\?/', 'replacement', $original, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a single character you're replacing, you may not need a preg_ solution: a "simple" str_replace may do the trick as well:

[www.php.net/str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure not to replace either question mark in the string `testing ??` you could do:

```
// using negative lookbehind/ahead to ensure that the question mark 
// doesn't have a "friend"
$new = preg_replace('/(?<!\?)\?(?!\?)/', 'replacement', $original);
```

If you are looking to only replace the first question mark in the string - chaos's answer is what you want